# Hiding a field in Black Berry

Tags: blackberry, hide, field

I would like to toggle two Fields on a screen, like a simulated tab screen.  I tried creating a HorizontalFieldManager and populating it with Field A, then to toggle deleteAll() and add() Field B.  Then Repeat to switch them. (Triggered by a button)  This works, but in the simulator is locks up after doing this five times.  I haven't tried it on a device yet.  Is there a better way to to this, or is this pretty much the only way to do something like that?

Comment: Like the whole UI is locking up? Can you background the app in the simulator with the end call button?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is covered by this support article: [Create tabbed view screens](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-tabbed-view-screens/ta-p/444969). I haven't tried it though.